# Building expression that involves fields in Layer Properties (size, rotation) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression

I need to build an expression in QGIS that involves fields like Size, Rotation or Offset.

Is there any method how I could involve these fields when I am building the expression?

[image]

So I have a Point layer and size of points is set to eg. 3 (Map unit) and I have this Column MERITKO in Attribute table that I need to change the size of each point so what I need is to build the expression: **Size * MERITKO**

How can I do that?

Comment: Two problems: 1) "multiply a size of Points and Texts" is unclear 2) Questions here in GIS SE are expected to be focused on one topic, but procedures for both ArcGIS and QGIS makes this two questions.  Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/182548/edit) the question

Comment: A point has no size, so cannot be "multiplied" in order to be larger. Perhaps you want to *buffer* a point (and therefore create a polygon), given an attribute that determines the size of the buffer?

Comment: Yes you can build an expression involving those fields.  What is the logic behind the expression.  Also can we see a screenshot of your attribute table for the layer, that would help answer your question.

Comment: Is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 3):

Usually we can set the size of symbols by the field like below:

(1) In the layer property window, set `Unit` (your case= `Map Units`) and click on a small icon (so-called `Data defined override`) on the right of `Size`. Please note you do not have to set the Size (you want it `3.0` for the base case) at the moment.

[image]

(2) Click on `Edit` and then give an expression as required. In this case you need `3 * "MERITKO"`. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the offset, it's little bit different.It takes a string as input:
[image]

Here we can use an expression:

```
format('%1,%2',  "DeltaX" ,  "DeltaY" )
```

Where DeltaX and DeltaY can be the field column in your table.

Comment: Yes `offset` was definitly important. Good catch, thanks!